# Jasper Report Freeze title of html report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm looking to find a solution that will 'freeze' or fix the title band of an HTML report generated by Jasper Reports 4.*.  The table body should be scroll-able while the title always remains on top.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can do this by using CSS. the details band will be in table, make it fixed height and overflow will be scrollable.

In the title band, you will have either static text or text element, there you can put css styles, try to set position = fixed, this will make your title part fixed on the page.

The other way is to use jQuery, check css class/id of your title and you can write jquery to change css position property to position:fixed.